# Web.config issue In memberShip Provider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, asp.net-membership

I'm trying to use devart SimpleMembership and SimpleRole Providers for Oracle in ASP.NET MVC I folowed this [Tutorial](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/articles/extendedmembership-tutorial.html) but in **step 7** when I lunch my app I got this error :

```
    Erreur HTTP 500.19 - Internal Server Error 
    Unable to access the page you requested because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
Error description : Unable to read configuration section 'membership' because a declaration section is missing
```

at this line (he's colored with red):

```
<membership defaultProvider="MySqlExtendedMembershipProvider">
```

and this is part of my web.config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <membership defaultProvider="MySqlExtendedMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
      <remove name="OracleExtendedMembershipProvider"/>
      <add name="OracleExtendedMembershipProvider" type="Devart.Data.Oracle.Web.Providers.OracleExtendedMembershipProvider,
        Devart.Data.Oracle.Web, Version=8.3.135.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701"
        description="dotConnect for Oracle extended membership provider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
    </providers>
  </membership>
  <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="OracleExtendedRoleProvider">
    <providers>
      <remove name="OracleExtendedRoleProvider"/>
      <add name="OracleExtendedRoleProvider" type="Devart.Data.Oracle.Web.Providers.OracleExtendedRoleProvider,
          Devart.Data.Oracle.Web, Version=8.3.135.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701"
          description="dotConnect for Oracle extended role provider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
    </providers>
  </roleManager>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="User Id=devart;Password=1234;Data Source=localhost:1521" providerName="Devart.Data.Oracle" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

So What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To slove this problem I had to move the `membership element` (and children) as well as the `roleManager element` inside of the `system.web` element. Like this :

```
<system.web>
    <membership ... > </membership>
  <roleManager ...> </roleManger>
  ...
  </system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

For fixing the issue please replace:

```
<membership defaultProvider="MySqlExtendedMembershipProvider">
```

with:

```
<membership defaultProvider="OracleExtendedMembershipProvider">
```

There is a misprint in our tutorial, we'll fix it.
The same information but without misprint is present in our documentation http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/?ExtendedMembership-Tutorial.html

Comment: I have changed this Already always same problem `<membership defaultProvider="OracleExtendedMembershipProvider"/>` is colored with red and same error .